# Why doesn't the google closure compile keep reused indexes in variables?

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler

[This MWE](https://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home#code%3D%252F%252F%2520%253D%253DClosureCompiler%253D%253D%250A%252F%252F%2520%2540output_file_name%2520default.js%250A%252F%252F%2520%2540compilation_level%2520SIMPLE_OPTIMIZATIONS%250A%252F%252F%2520%2540formatting%2520pretty_print%250A%252F%252F%2520%253D%253D%252FClosureCompiler%253D%253D%250A%250Avar%2520foo%2520%253D%2520new%2520function()%2520%257B%250A%2520%2520var%2520keyA%2520%253D%2520'some-very-long-key'%253B%250A%2520%2520var%2520keyB%2520%253D%2520'another-key'%253B%250A%2520%2520this.bar%2520%253D%2520function()%2520%257B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520obj%255BkeyA%255D%2520%253D%2520%257B%257D%253B%250A%2520%2520%257D%250A%2520%2520this.baz%2520%253D%2520function(data)%2520%257B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520obj%255BkeyA%255D%255BkeyB%255D%2520%253D%2520data%253B%250A%2520%2520%257D%250A%257D()%253B) shows how the google closure compiler exchanges the short `obj[keyA]` for the longer `obj["some-very-long-key"]`:

Input javascript:

```
var foo = new function() {
  var keyA = 'some-very-long-key';
  var keyB = 'another-key';
  this.bar = function() {
    obj[keyA] = {};
  }
  this.baz = function(data) {
    obj[keyA][keyB] = data;
  }
}();
```

Google closure compiler output:

```
var foo = new function() {
  this.bar = function() {
    obj["some-very-long-key"] = {};
  };
  this.baz = function(a) {
    obj["some-very-long-key"]["another-key"] = a;
  };
};
```

---

If I remove the wrapping function, [it works as I expected it to](https://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home#code%3D%252F%252F%2520%253D%253DClosureCompiler%253D%253D%250A%252F%252F%2520%2540output_file_name%2520default.js%250A%252F%252F%2520%2540compilation_level%2520SIMPLE_OPTIMIZATIONS%250A%252F%252F%2520%2540formatting%2520pretty_print%250A%252F%252F%2520%253D%253D%252FClosureCompiler%253D%253D%250A%250A%2520%2520var%2520keyA%2520%253D%2520'some-very-long-key'%253B%250A%2520%2520var%2520keyB%2520%253D%2520'another-key'%253B%250A%2520%2520function%2520bar()%2520%257B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520obj%255BkeyA%255D%2520%253D%2520%257B%257D%253B%250A%2520%2520%257D%250A%2520%2520function%2520baz(data)%2520%257B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520obj%255BkeyA%255D%255BkeyB%255D%2520%253D%2520data%253B%250A%2520%2520%257D):

Input javascript:

```
var keyA = 'some-very-long-key';
var keyB = 'another-key';
function bar() {
  obj[keyA] = {};
}
function baz(data) {
  obj[keyA][keyB] = data;
}
```

Google closure compiler output:

```
var keyA = "some-very-long-key", keyB = "another-key";
function bar() {
  obj[keyA] = {};
}
function baz(a) {
  obj[keyA][keyB] = a;
}
;
```

---

Because I use a long key quite often in my project, the code gets larger than it could be, if google closure compiler kept the string literal in the variable.

- What causes this behaviour?
- How can I get it to store the string literal inside a variable and use that variable (which has a shorter name) as index, whilst keeping the whole thing inside a constructor?

---

**Update 1:** I know that my wanted result might perform ever so slightly worse, but I'd rather take the much shorter code.

Comment: in reality, I'm using curl instead of the webUI. [The API](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/api-ref) doesn't seem to support such a flag.

Comment: I think I posted that comment by mistake. I'll post the one I meant to post below. :-)

Comment: The reason it does that in one situation and not another is easy: In your second block, `keyA` and `keyB` could be changed. I think you want to set `inlineVariables` option to `false`, but I don't think you can do that through the web UI or even the compiler app command-line options, I think you have to write a Java program and call the compiler with a custom options object. The JavaDoc for the option ([here](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/blob/0695307e84bf878949c894333dd4907ffa595cd0/src/com/google/javascript/jscomp/CompilerOptions.java)) is literally just "Inlines variables".

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14576782/closure-compiler-options

Comment: Don't forget to accept Chad's answer -- or fill in more details, if that answer doesn't resolve it for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of gzip - it usually makes the compressed size smaller. It's even [in the FAQ](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/wiki/FAQ#closure-compiler-inlined-all-my-strings-which-made-my-code-size-bigger-why-did-it-do-that)

Comment: *Doh!* I knew that...once...years ago.